# solve strtok While loop breaks outer while loop problem

Tags: c

If i remove while loop of strtok, the outer while loop can continues until i type exit. But the outer while loop breaks with strtok loop inside. I wonder why this happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit() function
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char input[1024];
    fgets(input,1024,stdin);
    do
    {
        printf("%s\n",input);
        char* token = strtok(input, " ");
        while (token) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        fgets(input,1024,stdin);
    }while (strcmp(input, "exit\n") == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings match, not `1`.

Comment: Your loop won't allow the user to type `exit` on the first line. Is that intentional?

Comment: That's an impressive array of unnecessary headers.  Including `<stdlib.h>` twice is curious, too.  You need just two: `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>`.  You should probsbly use a top-checked `while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != 0)` loop. You're also double spacing the information with that first `printf()` statement — which doesn't matter, but you might prefer not to.

Comment: @Barmar hi, i want to stop this loop when user type exit. That's why i use 1

Comment: But `strcmp` is not defined to return `1`. From the [strcmp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp): "return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2 ". That is, if the strings are not equal it is not guaranteed to return `1`. So condition should be `!=0`.

Comment: @kaylum thank you so much!! i see where the problem comes from !!!    :p

Comment: @JonathanLeffler hi , i dont want double space. is there any way to avoid that ?thx

Comment: Since `fgets()` includes the newline, your format string can omit it.  Keep the `”%s”`; omitting it leaves your code vulnerable to attack. Granted, that’s not a major problem here, but it isss c as well to get into good habits now.  Using `fputs()` would be another option; using `puts()` would give you double spacing again.

Comment: What about the fact that you don't check for `exit` until the second input. Why do you do that? Use a `while` loop instead of a `do-while` loop so you check every input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these statements

```
    fgets(input,1024,stdin);
}while (strcmp(input, "exit\n") == 1)
```

Write the following

```
}while ( fgets(input,1024,stdin) != NULL && strcmp(input, "exit\n") != 0 );
```

The function `strcmp` can return any non-zero value if two strings are unequal.